# how to get outputStream chunks in sync mode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, stream, async-await

is there a way to convert stream to buffer in sync mode?
I need to get it like:

```
let newBuffer = outputStream.getDataSync();
```

rather than `outputStream.on('data'...` like below

```
let newBuffer = convertStream(outputStream);

function convertStream(strm) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    strm.on('data', (chunk) => {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', () => {
      resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
    }).on('error', (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}
```

I cannot use await for convertStream because the function I call it from is not async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about still using stream and async, but also using async iterator (`for await`)?

```
async function collectStream()
    let whole = [];
    for await (const chunk of outputStream) {
        whole.push(chunk);
    }
    return whole;
}

// another async function somewhere
async function main() {
    await collectStream();
}
```

But what if you *really* need to make it async? You can use [deasync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync) on `collectStream().then`. `deasync.loopWhile` can turn promise (async function) or callback into a sync one.

It's okay for a single-tenant app like CLI tools, but I don't recommend it on a multi-tenant system like a web server, as you could block the event loop. It's better to use async functions instead on web servers.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use `await` by wrapping the the call to `convertStream()` in an [Immediately Invoked Async Function Expression](http://2ality.com/2016/10/async-function-tips.html#immediately-invoked-async-function-expressions).

```js
function foo() {
  return Promise.resolve('bar');
}

(async function() { console.log(await foo()); })();
```

Comment: as I said I cannot make main function async:
(async function().. so I thought there is a sync way to work with outputstreams

Comment: @VladP it's really very ill-advised to buffer streams synchronously like that. You'd basically be blocking the event loop for a non trivial amount of time waiting for all the chunks to come through. Why does the function need to be synchronous? Or is that just an arbitrary design choice?

Comment: @patrick aand if you block the event loop, no data will arrive in the stream... :)

Answer (score 1):

A Stream is a flow of data. You cannot get a buffer synchronously, as the data in the stream might already started flowing, or will arrive somewhen.

> I cannot use await for convertStream because the function I call it from is not async

Then make that function you call from async?

Answer (score 0):

It is said that asynchrony is contagious: as soon as you have one asynchronous bit in your flow, all the dependent flow needs to be asynchronous. Streams are asynchronous by nature, so you can only simplify your code via synchronous-looking async-await.

BTW, the [asynchronous iterator interface for streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_symbol_asynciterator) may be the most concise way to do this.